# Using wmic to start a process on a remote machine as part of a .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, execution, wmic

TL;DR - I simply want a way to start a powerpoint presentation on a remote machine via command line / batch file using wmic (not PSEXEC).

A litte info...

I am trying to run a process on a remote machine on our network (POWERPNT.EXE). The purpose of this is that we have a .pptx presentation running on a TV in an entrance and this needs updating with info every day. Traditionally this has been done with VNC and simply editing the file but I want to improve this as the screen is part of a multi monitor set up and this can cause issues eslewhere.

So, my batch file will :

1. Kill the process on the remote machine running the .pptx
2. Open the file stored on the remote machine's desktop locally in Powerpoint
3. After saving the presentation in step 2, run the pptx. slide in auto show mode on the remote machine.

I have 1 and 2 working but am struggling to get the final part to run POWERPNT.EXE on the remote.

Here is my code:

```
wmic /node:"REMOTE-MACHINE-NAME" process call create "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE /s \\REMOTE-MACHINE-NAME\SHARED-FOLDER\Presentation.pptx"
```

I don't want to use PSEXEC as not all operators that need to change this slide will have access to that on their PC's.

Comment: I could imagine that the problem is caused by the spaces and in the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE` (however, please recheck if there is really a `root` directory!); you could perhaps try this: `wmic /node:"REMOTE-MACHINE-NAME" process call create ^""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE" /s "\\REMOTE-MACHINE-NAME\SHARED-FOLDER\Presentation.pptx"^"`

Comment: No luck with that I am afraid. I just get 'Invalid format'. There is a root directory in the path and I think the spaces are ok as the path is in " ".

I have been doing some more troubleshooting and have found that the process is being created and is visible in taskman of the remote machine but Powerpoint does not start in the task bar and the presentation (or the editor) are nowhere to be seen.

Even dropping the path to the presentation I cannot get Powerpoint to actually run on the remote machine - although as above, the process is created in taskman!

Comment: WMIC can't create visible windows on remote machines. The principal is you can't affect the logged on user's experience.

Comment: Agh ... so wmic is not going to work for me in this case it seems. No workaround to that I assume? Would be open to other suggestions on how to achieve the desired outcome if anyone has any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Only psexec unless you script powerpoint to reload itself or something. You can use help to logon to an existing logon.  See *Remote Assistance* (it's like a live terminal server) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Remote_Assistance.

Comment: Ok, maybe I need to rethink this. Wonder if I can somehow remotely run a bath file on the remote machine that will start PowerPoint?